# DB insert takes a long time

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using following code to insert the data into a table.

```
public CourseDB addcourseByType(CourseDB rmdb) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COURSE_NAME, rmdb.getcourse_name()); 
            values.put(CATEGORY_COURSE_TYPE, rmdb.getcategory_course_type()); 
            values.put(COURSE_CRS, rmdb.getcourse_crs());
            values.put(CATEGORY_ID_FOR, rmdb.getcat_foreign_id()); // Contact
            db.insert(TABLE_COURSE, null, values);

            String selectQuery = "SELECT " + COURSE_ID + " FROM "
                + TABLE_COURSE + " WHERE " + COURSE_CRS + "='"
                + rmdb.getcourse_crs() + "'" + " AND " + CATEGORY_ID_FOR
                + "='" + rmdb.getcat_foreign_id() + "'";
            SQLiteDatabase db1 = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db1.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                     rmdb.setcourse_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();

        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
          }
       db.close();
       return rmdb;
}
```

Please let me know if there is any way I can change the code to add the values faster, I'm  getting the data in `JSON` format from the file, storing it as array and passing it to the above method.

**Asmita**

I tried the suggestions and was able to reduce the insertion time from 16 to 11 secs.Please have a look at me new code. Is it possible to reduce it further.

```
// //convert string to JSONArray
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(bufferString);
                if (bufferString.isEmpty()) {


                } else {



                    db.deleteAllCourseByTypeDB(type);
                }


                boolean eventFlag = false;
                db.beginTransaction();
                SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = db.getWritableDatabase();

                 long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                for (int j = 0; j < jArray.length(); j++) {
            long insideStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(j);
            String crsCd = (json_data.getString("crsCd"));
            String crsTitle = (json_data.getString("crsTitle"));
        System.out.println("Time for one JSON parsing "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-insideStart));

            try
                {

                    values.put(COURSE_NAME, crsTitle);                          values.put(CATEGORY_COURSE_TYPE, type); // Contact
                                                                                            // Name
                        values.put(COURSE_CRS, crsCd);
                        values.put(CATEGORY_ID_FOR, id_notebook2); // Contact
                        sqlDB.insert(TABLE_COURSE, null, values);
                        //Error in between database transaction 


                    }
                      finally {

                      }
                    System.out.println("Time for one One Looping "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-insideStart));

                }

                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                db.endTransaction();
                db.close();
                long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("this is my timer "+(endTime-startTime)/1000);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: are you using sqlite helper? or you directly implemtnted the db in your acticity?

Comment: My Database class extends  SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: good!. how you sending the data from your code to open helper?!

Comment: @Asmi Why do you use select query while inserting data? If you intend only to insert data then remove code from `String` to `cursor.close()`.

Comment: will remove select query to different and then try

Comment: It is still taking the same amount of time, for 400 records insertion and display takes about 16 secs

Comment: I m callling the addcourseByType method from my fragment

Comment: try to implement UNION statement. It will be much more faster. The only time that you will spend will be for `for` statement to populate the right sql statement. That's all.

Comment: remove system.out.println time will get reduced by 2 sec

Comment: @Android-Developer How do I use UNION in above scenario

Comment: values.put(COURSE_NAME, crsTitle);                          values.put(CATEGORY_COURSE_TYPE, type); 
values.put(COURSE_CRS, crsCd);
values.put(CATEGORY_ID_FOR, id_notebook2); 
  sqlDB.insert(TABLE_COURSE, null, values);

Comment: to use UNION you don't need any ContentValues, you just construct a string which will be your sql statement and query it using your database helper. check the edited answer

Answer (score 3):

You did insertion and selection query in same method separate method into two one for insertion and one for selection and try.
hope it helps.

**EDIT:**

after long time found one solution

it works very quick.....

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)";
db.beginTransaction();

SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);

for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    stmt.bindString(1, values.get(i).column1);
    stmt.bindString(2, values.get(i).column2);
    stmt.execute();
    stmt.clearBindings();
}

db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
```

For 10,000 data it takes only 60sec.

Comment: can i know how much data you sending from activity

Comment: it is normal time taking to insert in the database. you can use the async task for db insertion so it will not affect your activity.

Comment: what is contactDB rmdb? in your code ? you sending the same database in side contactDB right?

Comment: this is an array for storing json

Comment: remove system.out.println time will get reduced by 2 sec

Comment: No much affect of removing the prints :(

Answer (score 0):

Why you are running rawquery in case you are aware with operation type. 
You can use [update](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) or [insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) or [select](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method specified in API to change the query.

Also if you can think only one result of cursor  then you may not need to have loop. Just move to first position and get the values.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need the second instance of your database class in same function :`SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();` and than `SQLiteDatabase db1 = this.getWritableDatabase();`. Use only `db`. Second of all as I can see your list take int as argument so this `rmdb.setcourse_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));` can be changed to `cursor.getInt();`. No need for extra conversion.

And at the end about the inserts the best way to achieve a really fast inserting of a big portion of data is to use something similar to this :

```
String insertSql = "REPLACE INTO requested_cards ";
for (int j = 0; j < requested_cards.length(); j++) {
  int id = 0;
  try {
    id = requested_cards.getInt(j);
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  if (j == 0) {
    insertSql += "SELECT " + my_id
            + " AS id, " + id
            + " AS cardId ";
  } else {
    insertSql += "UNION SELECT " + my_id
            + " , " + id + " ";
  }


 }
 dbHelper.executeSQL(insertSql);
```

Edit:

So your statement should look like this :

```
REPLACE INTO myTable 
SELECT myValueFromJSOn AS id, myAnotherValueFromJson AS name (and etc. depending on which rows you want to insert/update) 
UNION SELECT myValueFromJSON , myAnotherValueFromJSON
UNION SELECT myValueFromJSON, myAnotherValueFromJSON...
```

and that's all.

Comment: Please explain the above code, REPLACE INTO? I get error  at id = requested_cards.getInt(j);

Comment: requested_cards in my situation is JSONArray which I am using to get the current item (id). And i use Replace Into for one reason. For example I am trying to insert a data which is already in the database. In normal INSERT statement that will throw an error for duplicate data. Using replace will update the values which are already been in the database. If no data found with given values, it will insert them. By using UNION you can insert 100000 values doing just `dbHelper.executeSQL(insertSql);` It's just simple.

Answer (score 0):

If your primary key is INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT then your key is an alias to the row id, and row id is exactly that which is retuned by db.insert. See [here](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid). So, you don't need to make a select for obtaining id.

Comment: I have not set as autoincrement, will try it and see the result

Comment: @Asmi - my insertion technique in my apps was totally based on autoincrement ids returning by insert method and it works fine.